# Good Practice mvc conditional button and its code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm coding an MVC3 application with ajax and I got a situation.

I have to show na Button only if an condition is true. Ok its easy to do.

```
@if (Model.AAA == ENUM.AAA)
    {
      <button>OK</button>
    }
```

but this button going to call an ajax function.

Now my doubt is, WHERE A PLACE MY AJAX CODE?

if I do this:

```
@if (Model.AAA == ENUM.AAA)
    {
      function OK(){
          $.ajax({}); 
      }

      <button>OK</button>
    }
```

it's sound ugly code!!!
It's seens that the code it' not in the right place but the ajax code is "safe", I mean, the ajax code will only exist if the button exist.

but if I place my code in head section, An advanced user will be able to call the ajax function.

or if a make an @if clause to enclose the script, I will duplicate code like this

```
<head type="text/javascript">
   @if (Model.AAA == ENUM.AAA){
      function OK(){
         $.ajax({});
      }
   }
</head>
....
<body>
   ....
    @if (Model.AAA == ENUM.AAA)
    {
      <button onclick="OK()">OK</button>
    }
    ....
 </body>
```

So, What is the best practice to face this situation, the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server should control the request call and check for the correct state. @Andrew Barber points this out, but that is not just leaving the browser open. But the advanced user could share the ajax request, with others that don't have permission, or use it maliciously

Trying to answer the question in a bit more depth, it could be not a simple script like this, but a file or some JS library, maybe you don't have control about the server you ajax is accessing. In that case, you'd probably want to duplicate the verification.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds almost like you are wanting to use the presence/lack of a snippet of Javascript code to control access to a call on your server. *Don't do that*.

Your server should *always* be evaluating if the action can be called by the user in question at that moment. What if the user leaves the page open in their browser, and some application state change happens that would block the user from calling that action... but their browser is still displaying the button? Or if a clever user decides to play around with your URLs by poking around in the source?

I would recommend just putting the javascript in a common location and calling it from there, as that keeps all your Javascript together.

Comment: Uhm. I think that I got the point. The point is, SERVER SIDE VALIDATIONS, right? So, if I follow this thought the best place javascript/ajax code is head section.. right? thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just have the one conditional in your markup, like you have:

```
@if (Model.AAA == ENUM.AAA)
{
  <button id="OkButton">OK</button>
}
```

Then tweak your Javascript slightly so you don't include Razor (that way it can be extracted into an external JS file):

```
<head type="text/javascript">

    WireUpButton();

    function WireUpButton() {
        var okbutton = document.getElementById("OkButton");

        if (okbutton) {
            okbutton.onclick = OK;
        }
    }

    function OK(){
     $.ajax({});
  }
</head>
```